# Please translate “Shem Yinone mechoilol maichovim” in a selicho for Tzom Gedaliah

Tags: fast-days, selichot, translation

Please could someone offer a translation of the phrase “*Shem Yinone mechoilol maichovim*” in the *Selicho* for *Tzom Gedaliah* that begins “*Oz Terem Nimtochu*” (near the beginning of the selichos)?

Comment: Would it be possible to [include the Hebrew](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13) of the phrase? I can't figure out what the words are from the transliteration, and don't have a copy of the _s'licha_ here.

Comment: Ah, found it: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2754&pgnum=470.

Comment: I found [a version](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42206&st=&pgnum=43) of that selicha that has a slightly different version of this phrase near the beginning: "זוהר שם ינון מחובים"

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I wonder whether it's been censored at some point (perhaps by Jews). "Wounded for sins" is one way to translate the words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Chabad Selichot translates it](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15946&pgnum=320) as:

> [and] the brightness of the name Yinon [Mashiach; the anointed redeemer of Israel]
>   which became profaned by sins.

It has the Hebrew as "*Zohar shem yinon m'cholal meychovim*"

According to [Lithuanian version of "Seder Selichot Mefureshet - Be'er Ya'akov"](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49117&pgnum=346) by "חיים צבי פנט":

- Yinon refers to Moshiach, as the Talmud (Pesachim 54A) explains Tehillim 72:17.
- Based on [Yishaya 53:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1053.htm#5), M'cholal means "Crushed", and Meychovim means "from our sins"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the trustworthiness of the Saul Kleiman of Kansas City who [published in 1942](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2754&pgnum=470), but according to him, q.v., *zohar shem yinon m'cholal mechovim* means something like "the shiny name of *mashiach*, who's ill from sins/debts" (one of the various things listed as having been created before the world).

Comment: You could improve this answer by giving some indication of whom you're quoting beyond a link.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, good point: done.

Comment: In the sefer you referenced, he says that that "m'cholal mechovim" is based on Yishaya 53:5. There it says: " וְהוּא מְחֹלָל מִפְּשָׁעֵנוּ" and the JPS translation is "But he was wounded because of our transgressions". If so the translation might be something close to *"The radiance of the name of Moshiach, which has become wounded by our sins".* - similar to how the Chabad Slichot translates it: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15946&pgnum=320

Comment: @Menachem, hm, yes that's what the _Malbim_ says also. Sorry. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This *selicha* enumerates the seven items that were created before the world was created (see Pesachim 54A). They are: Torah, repentance, *Gan Eden*, *Gehinnom*, the Heavenly Throne, The Holy Temple and the Name of *Moshiach*. The phrase  “*Shem Yinone mechoilol maichovim*” (in my Selichos "*Zohar*" instead of "*Shem*") means the light of Moshiach known as "*Yinone*" (Psalms 72:17) who we hope will redeem us from our debts (sins).